# Check if any available product has specific attribute

Tags: custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic

How can you check if there are any products with a specific product attribute in the shop?

I could query (eg. with `wc_get_products()`) all products and check if they (or their variations) are in stock and then collect all the attribute values in an array and test the specific attribute against that array.

However, I think that sounds like a huge amount of database requests so I wondered if there is an easier path that I am missing.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query 
and this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272619/retrieve-products-with-specific-attribute-and-in-category-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that solved the problem:

```
$woo_args = array(
    'status'        => 'publish',
    'limit'         => 1,
    'stock_status'  => 'instock',
    'brand'         => 99
);
$products = wc_get_products($woo_args);

if (count($products) == 0){
   //No product with the custom attribute id=99
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'my_handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2);
function my_handle_custom_query_var($query, $query_vars) {
    if (!empty($query_vars['brand'])){
        $query['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_brand',
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $query_vars['brand'],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```